# How to display a decimal value but remove decimal

Tags: format, decimal

lets say that I have a value like $1.25. I want display just the .25 but the decimal removed so that i can display you have 1 dollar and 25 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that javascript and html is fine you could do it like this:

```
<div id="output"></div> 

<script>
var cost = 1.25;
var beforeDec = Math.abs((cost).toFixed(0));
var afterDec = 100*(cost - beforeDec);

if (beforeDec < 1) {
var dollar = " dollars";
} else {
var dollar = " dollar";
}

if (afterDec > 1) {    
var cent = " cents"; 
} else {
var cent = " cent";
}


document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You have " + beforeDec + dollar + " and " + afterDec + cent + ".";

</script>
```

You can try the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/x9ygp0x0/).